# Extract time from moment js object

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, momentjs, angular-moment

How do i extract the time using moment.js?

```
"2015-01-16T12:00:00"
```

It should return "12:00:00 pm".
The string return will be passed to the timepicker control below.

```
http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If you read the docs (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) you can find this format:

```
moment("2015-01-16T12:00:00").format("hh:mm:ss a")
```

See JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bjolja/6mn32xhu/

Comment: For instance moment("2015-01-16T16:00:00").format("HH:mm:ss a")
returns as "16:00:00 pm" ??? it should be "4:00:00 pm" !

Comment: Yes, take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Bjolja/6mn32xhu/

What do you mean it did not work? Error message? Wrong format on output?

Comment: i expect "4:00:00 pm" not 16pm

Comment: Change HH to hh, so moment("2015-01-16T16:00:00").format("hh:mm:ss a"). I've updated the fiddle aswell

Answer (score 35):

You can do something like this

```
var now = moment();
var time = now.hour() + ':' + now.minutes() + ':' + now.seconds();
time = time + ((now.hour()) >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM');
```

Comment: The approach doesn't consider the timezone

Answer (score 9):

Use `format` method with a specific pattern to extract the time.
Working example

```js
var myDate = "2017-08-30T14:24:03";
console.log(moment(myDate).format("HH:mm")); // 24 hour format
console.log(moment(myDate).format("hh:mm a")); // use 'A' for uppercase AM/PM
console.log(moment(myDate).format("hh:mm:ss A")); // with milliseconds
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the good way using formats:

```
const now = moment()
now.format("hh:mm:ss K") // 1:00:00 PM
now.format("HH:mm:ss") // 13:00:00
```

Red more about [moment sring format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)