# How to get am pm from the date time string using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a string as `Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 AM/PM` and I have to convert this into a string like `11:00 AM/PM` using moment js.

The problem here is that I am unable to get `AM` or `PM` from the date time string.

I am doing this:

```
moment(Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 AM, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm').format('hh:mm A')
```

and it is working fine as I am getting `11:00 AM` but if the string has `PM` in it it is still giving `AM` in the output.

like this `moment(Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 PM, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm').format('hh:mm A')` is also giving `11:00 AM` in output instead of `11:00 PM`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract time from moment js object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978819/extract-time-from-moment-js-object)

Comment: @Alexander the linked question is about formatting, the issue here is about parsing.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You are using the wrong format tokens when parsing your input. You should use `ddd` for an abbreviation of the name of day of the week,  `DD` for day of the month, `MMM` for an abbreviation of the month's name, `YYYY` for the year, `hh` for the `1-12` hour, `mm` for minutes and `A` for `AM/PM`. See [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs.

Here is a working live sample:

```js
console.log( moment('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 AM', 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm A').format('hh:mm A') );
console.log( moment('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 PM', 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm A').format('hh:mm A') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 29):

Convert the string to date using `Date` object

```
var myDate = new Date('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 06:00 PM');
```

working solution:

```js
var myDate= new Date('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 06:00 PM');
var now = new Date();
console.log(moment(myDate).format('HH:mm')); // 24 hour format 
console.log(moment(myDate).format('hh:mm')); // 12 hour format
console.log(moment(myDate).format('hh:mm A'));
console.log(moment(myDate).format('hh:mm a'));
console.log("Now: " + moment(now).format('hh:mm A'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 15):

The previously  mentioned answers are perfect. But there are some other ways also

```
console.log( moment('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 PM', 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm A').format('LT') );
```

11:00 PM

```
moment().format('LT');   // 5:50 PM
moment().format('LTS');  // 5:50:35 PM
moment().format('L');    // 18/02/2022
moment().format('l');    // 18/2/2022
moment().format('LL');   // 18 February 2022
moment().format('ll');   // 18 Feb 2022
moment().format('LLL');  // 18 February 2022 5:50 PM
moment().format('lll');  // 18 Feb 2022 5:50 PM
moment().format('LLLL'); // Friday, 18 February 2022 5:50 PM
moment().format('llll');
```

For more information please visit https://momentjs.com/