# Format timestamp without timezone to datetime-local in moment

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

Timestamp is "2019-12-30 13:59:00" and I want to convert it to "30/12/2019 1:59 pm" .

I tried several methods :

`moment(this.event.start,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm');`
`moment(this.event.start,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm a');`

All methods show a correct result but do not show am/pm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get am pm from the date time string using moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971954/how-to-get-am-pm-from-the-date-time-string-using-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

You tried this?

`moment(this.event.start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss a').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm a'));`