# How to set am/pm in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I am using **new Date()** to create a customize time, and also I'm using a function to format time in am/pm:

```js
const formatTimeAMPM = (date, midnight = { am: "AM", pm: "PM" }) => {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? ` ${midnight.am}` : ` ${midnight.pm}`;
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  var strTime = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm;
  return strTime;
};

let startDate = new Date(Date.now());
console.log('before change :',formatTimeAMPM(startDate));
startDate.setHours(8, 30, 0, 0);
console.log('after change :',formatTimeAMPM(startDate));
```

If you run the snippet, you will see console logs the 8:30 pm ,  Can anyone tell me how to set am for it when I change hour the startDate ?

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972009/2407212

Comment: Use moment.js.  Why rewrite the wheel?  Formatting, parsing, timezones, differences...

Comment: moment has lots of features but moment.min.js size is 16.7k, and I'm not renting a truck to take a needle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your am/pm check is backwards:

```
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? ` ${midnight.am}` : ` ${midnight.pm}`;
```

If the hour is >= 12, it should be PM not AM, so it should be:

```
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? ` ${midnight.pm}` : ` ${midnight.am}`;
```

Now if you run it, it will show `8:30 AM` and if you set the hour to `20` it will show `8:30 PM`

This will fix your current issue but it would be better to use an existing library for date formatting since it can get complicated, especially with i18n. There a couple popular ones such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) and [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) that will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: The function works as well, and I've used it elsewhere, my question is about how to set am when I change the hour and minutes

Comment: Hour `8` is 8 AM so the logic should be inversed. If you simply want to show 8 AM with your current logic, you would set the hour to `20`, i.e.: `startDate.setHours(20, 30, 0, 0);`.