# TimePicker return object not time angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, timepicker

how can i make timepicker in form return the time i chose .

TimePicker in form :

```
 <label class="padd"> Time of visiting </label>
 <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="meridianTime" [meridian]="meridian" 
 formControlName="time" id="time"  ></ngb-timepicker>
```

TypeScript part:

```
 defaultTime = {hour: 13, minute: 30};
 customTime: NgbTimeStruct = {hour: 13, minute: 30, second: 0};
 hourStep = 1;
 minuteStep = 15;
```

Comment: What is actual result and what is expected? Is typescript parth is actual result?

Comment: i want to return time like 01:00 AM but it's return [object object] how can i return time ?

Comment: Where exactly do you get object object? `this. meridianTime`? Can you do `JSON.stringify(<timeObj>)`

Comment: i get [object Object] in table .. i make a form to choose time then i pass values to table but i have object Object

Comment: Yes because component output that date as object. You need to convert it before usage. See docs in my answer.

Comment: ya i see it but i can't convert this object to numbers (time)

Comment: What mean you can't convert :) just do it. Make a function or pipe and that's all.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have time. Here is docs: [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/api)

You have time as hour, minute, second props. You can convert it to whatever you need. To convert you can use internal JavaScript API: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or some libraries like [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/). Or something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979128/2898694 :)

So you have date in timepicker format. As object I mean. You can write something like this:

```
prepareDate(dateAsObject) {
  return dateAsObject.hour + ':' + dateAsObject.minute + ':' + dateAsObjet.second;
}
```

This is first thing in my head. Of course you can prepare date as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dateAsObject.toLocaleTimeString()`, you will get the time in 24-hour format.